# nginx API cross origin calls not working only from some browsers

Tags: django, nginx, https, network-programming, firewall

TLDR: React app's API calls are returning with status code 200 but without body in response, happens only when accessing the web app from some browsers.

I have a React + Django application deployed using nginx and uwsgi on a single centOS7 VM.

The React app is served by nginx on the domain, and when users log in on the javascript app, REST API requests are made to the same nginx on a sub domain (ie: backend.mydomain.com), for things like validate token and fetch data.

This works on all recent version of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Edge. However, some users have complained that they could not log in from their work network. They can visit the site, so obviously the javascript application is served to them, but when they log in, all of the requests come back with status 200, except the response has an empty body. (and the log in requires few pieces of information to be sent back with the log in response to work).

For example, when I log in from where I am, I would get response with status=200, and a json object with few parameters in the body of the response.

But when one of the users showed me the same from their browser, they get Status=200 back, but the Response is empty. They are using the same version of browsers as I have. They tried both Firefox and Chrome with the same behaviours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finally getting hold of one of the user to send me some screenshots. I found the problem. In my browser that works with the site, the API calls to the backend had `Referrer Policy` set to `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` in the Headers. However on their browser, the same was showing up as `no-referrer-when-downgrade`.

I had not explicitly set the referrer policy so the browsers were using each of their default values, and it differed between different versions of browsers (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default)

To fix this, I added `add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin';` to the nginx.conf file and restarted the server. More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

The users who had trouble before can now access the site API resources after clearing cache in their browsers.